# Programmatically removing "review" from titles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, titles

It looks like we all agree that titles should never contain the word "Review" or "review" inside them. What about writing a small script to remove all such occurencies? ([4,369 such occurrencies](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=review) to be precise)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for taking the initiative to help improve question quality.  I see a few problems with this idea, though:

- If you automate any edits, please do so in a way that doesn't flood the front page.  You'll need to rate-limit the changes.
- If the title is bad, it is likely that other things need to be improved with the post as well.  Ideally, you should make all of those improvements at the same time.  (If you're going to take up space on the front page for old questions, then at least make it *good*.  Let's not fill it with junk.)
- What title do you use instead?  In many cases, a proper title might be completely different from the original.

Taking all of these considerations into account, I would say that human editing may be more appropriate than scripting.

Note that "Review" is already one of the blacklisted words for titles, so we should not be getting new questions with that word in the title.

Comment: Nice to know it is impossible to put "review" in a title now. Also you are right that human intervention is key to improve not only the title but also the question. For 4000+ question we are going to need a massive cooperation effort but we are a good community, we can do it!

Comment: Since what date is it blacklisted? I still see many, many questions with 'review' in the title.

Comment: @Mast: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1606/22222